# How can I add multiple conditions to a location-block conditional in NGINX configuration, or otherwise get same desired result?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, configuration, httpd, conditional

## Initial disclosure:

I'm new to nginx and struggling to understand its configuration principles; I have read a fair amount of the docs (including 'If Is Evil'), but still lack comprehension of many aspects.
I intend to implement an api gateway in the near future for production, but desire to implement the below-described controls in straight nginx config, if possible, in the testing phase

## Situation:

I have a service running behind an nginx reverse proxy at endpoint `https://foobar.org/foo/`.
I wish to disallow all unauthenticated requests to the proxied server *except* for one specific endpoint; lets call it
`/foo/anon_permitted`

## Problem:

I've tried to add an AND to the conditional within the location block like so :

```
`if ($http_authorization = "" && $request != https://foobar.org/foo/anon_permitted) { return 403; }`
```

However, nginx balks with an "invalid condition" error.  [Note: I've tried various formatting permutations of the above, to no avail]

I've tried some other of the available variables (`$request_url`, `$uri`, `$args`) from https://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html , but the result is the same.

Also, I'm aware that adding conditionals to the location block is explicitly advised against, so if there's a better way to go about this configuration altogether (aside from the aforementioned api gateway), I'm eager to learn it.

## Question:

Is there a way to achieve the desired result, i.e., return 403 *if condition 'a' and **not** condition 'b'*, using pure nginx configuration?  And if so, how?

Current (working except for desired conditional) nginx conf shown below for reference:

```
    server {
      server_name foobar.org www.foobar.org;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.html;
      try_files $uri /index.html;
  
      listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
      listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/foobar.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/foobar.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
      include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
  
    location /foo/ {
        default_type application/json;
        proxy_hide_header Content-Location;
        add_header Content-Location /api/$upstream_http_content_location;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        if ($http_authorization = "") { return 403; }
        proxy_pass http://foo_upstream/;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to check the requested URI using an `if` statement. Just create another `location` block and copy over the required statements.

For example:

```
location /foo/ {
    ...
    if ($http_authorization = "") { return 403; }
    proxy_pass http://foo_upstream/;
}
location /foo/anon_permitted {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://foo_upstream/anon_permitted;
}
```